# Why are my lights blinking and appliances slightly losing power?

Tags: electrical

Last week, we heard a loud click and I think the circuit breaker was triggered. I am not very sure because I was not there when it was fixed. Also, nobody knowledgeable about electrical was around. But during that time all electrical outlet was not functioning.

But after all power to the electrical outlets were restored, lights in the house started to blink and even the washing machine stops and the fans slightly seems to lose power from time to time.

What could be the problem?

Comment: Got an electric range or dryer? Turn it on, see if the symptoms change. **That's not a workaround, don't run your house like that, but it's a momentary diagnostic test.**

Comment: Call your power company before the electrician suggested in a current answer.  More often, but not always, the problem is on the power companies portion of the line.  The power company won’t charge you, the electrician will.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you might have a faulty main breaker or possibly a loose/bad connection on one leg of your service entrance cable, located at your electric meter.  We had the same issue years ago with a bad connection at the meter base and this will cause, what the electric company serviceman referred to, as a "brown out".  This is definitely something that needs to be addressed by a qualified electrician. Or at least someone knowledgeable about electricity.

Comment: First call out should be to the power utility, if the problem is not on their side then the qualified electrician.

Comment: I wasn't implying that the first call should be to an electrician, just "someone" qualified.  And yes, when we had the issue, the first call I made was to the electric company and they were the ones that found and corrected a loose & arcing connection at the meter base.  Just trying to stress the fact that this isn't an issue that should be ignored.

Comment: I realize that you weren’t trying to.  Reading your answer tho implies ‘call an electrician’.  Most electricians would likely divert the customer and say check with PowerCo first.  The dilemma comes when customer puts off making first call to the electrician until the next payday, and then finds out they could have called PowerCo immediately for a no charge.